# div tag inside table - html

Tags: html

This is my HTML table:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Host Name</th>
        <th>OS Name</th>
        <th>OS Architecture</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <div id = "tttt">
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
        </tr>
      </div>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

When I look up the `view source` in HTML , `<div>` tag seems to have shifted above the table. Any idea why this happening? I used `div` in that place because I want to populate the records via javascript.

Comment: `<div>` cannot be directly inside `<tbody>`

Comment: `div` is outside of `td` ???

Answer (score 5):

Your HTML is completely malformed - a `div` is under no condition allowed to be directly underneath a `tbody` element. What you are seeing is simply your browser trying to make something usable out of fundamentally broken input.

[From the standards on `tbody`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tbody.html):

> **Permitted contents**
>
> Zero or more `tr` elements

Nothing else, and certainly no `div`s.

Comment: humbly accepting the mistake. will change the table.

Answer (score 2):

`div` tags cannot be entered inside tables outside of a `td` or a `th` tag.
The `div` tag jumped outside of your table because your browser was trying to make sense of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Place `<div>` tags like this

`<td><div></div><td>`

Placing a `div` in a table is allowed inside a pair of `td` or `th` elements only.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the proper way of placing `div` inside a `table`.

Use `<td>` to place the **table data** i.e. your `div`.